# Using Win32_ScheduledJob to create jobs

Tags: wmi, wmic

I'm using the following command to create a job:

```
wmic job call create "C:\Windows\system32\defrag.exe",0,127,FALSE,TRUE,"********000000.000000-500"
```

But I keep getting an error:

```
Invalid format.
Hint: <paramlist> = <param> [, <paramlist>].
```

I've seen similar syntax online so I'm a little confused why it isn't working on my system.  Elevated prompt to administrator to further test.

I have noticed the help command for this method seems to be different from the MSDN description.

Help:

```
Call                    [ In/Out ]Params&type                   Status
====                    =====================                   ======
Create                  [IN ]Command(STRING)                    (null)

                        [IN ]DaysOfMonth(UINT32)

                        [IN ]DaysOfWeek(UINT32)

                        [IN ]InteractWithDesktop(BOOLEAN)

                        [IN ]RunRepeatedly(BOOLEAN)

                        [IN ]StartTime(DATETIME)

                        [OUT]JobId(UINT32)
```

MSDN Link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389389(v=vs.85).aspx

Trying to avoid the use of PowerShell (Get-WmiObject).  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You should specify each property name as well:

> wmic job call create Command="C:\Windows\system32\defrag.exe",DaysOfMonth=0,DaysOfWeek=127,InteractWithDesktop=FALSE,RunRepeatedly=TRUE,StartTime="********000000.000000-500"

```
Executing (Win32_ScheduledJob)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        JobId = 1;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

Also `DaysOfMonth=0` and `DaysOfWeek=127` are incorrect values according to MSDN.